# How do I make a Little Schemer like layout in latex?

Tags: latex, layout

I want to make a two-column table that spans the entire page and is laid out something like this:

```
===================================
Column 1 text         Column 2 text
===================================
Column 1 text         Column 2 text
that wraps.
===================================
```

Where the equal signs are horizontal rules.  For a (better) example of what I'm asking for, see this [sample chapter of the Little Schemer](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/BTLS/sample.ps).  How can I create something similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should get you a good chunk of what you want:

```
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{ l l }
  \hline
  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog & Another example of text \\
  \hline
  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog & Another example of text \\
\end{tabular*}
```

Some explanation:

- The `tabular*` environment lets you set a lot of layout options that the simpler `tabular` environment doesn't, such as widths.
- The first argument to `tabular*`, `\textwidth`, tells LaTeX to use the entire width of the page.
- The second argument, `l l`, is just like that of `tabular`.
- The `\hline` command inserts a horizontal line.

Comment: You should also change the `l` s to `p` or the text won't wrap